# ignore directory while redirecting ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have URL http://172.16.59.152/ITMS_PNS_TEST/DashboardDailyDuty/DashboardDailyDuty

in ASP.NET MVC 4,,

i want to ignore ITMS_PNS_TEST when redirecting to another page how to do????

my RouteConfig is

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id1}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "ScheduleLogin", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "MultipleDutyOption",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "MultipleDutyOption", action = "RouteMergeApply", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
    }
```

Comment: Show the code you are using to do so?

Comment: I use attribute based routing in MVC 5 and its very easy there. You can do a something similar using MVC 4. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/attribute-based-routing-in-asp-net-web-api-and-mvc-4/